# Multiple Foreign key with a same primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express as a database server.

I have the following two tables between which I want to create PK-FK relationship.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Account]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ACCOUNTNAME] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [ACCOUNTTYPE] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CREATE_TIMESTAMP] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [LAST_EDIT_TIMESTAMP] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [OPENING_BALANCE] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [OPENING_BALANCE_TYPE] [nvarchar](50) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Account] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Voucher]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [VOUCHERTYPE] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [VOUCHERNO] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [AMOUNT] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [DRPARTY] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CRPARTY] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DETAILS] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ORIGIN] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ORIGINID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ORIGINDETAILS] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [CREATE_TIMESTAMP] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT ('1900-01-01T00:00:00.000'),
    [LAST_EDIT_TIMESTAMP] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT ('1900-01-01T00:00:00.000'),
    [TRANSACTION_TYPE] [nvarchar](50) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Voucher] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

This is the error I am getting when creating FK relationship via Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. Both tables are empty.

> 'Account' table saved successfully
>   'Voucher' table - Unable to create relationship 'FK_Voucher_Account1'. The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Voucher_Account1". The conflict occurred in database "SKUMAR", table "dbo.Account", column 'ID'

I want to create a relation between `Account.ID -> Voucher.DRPARTY` and `Account.ID -> Voucher.CRPARTY` but I am unable to create second FK relationship.

May I know how to solve this?

Comment: What is the error? Do your tables contain data already?

Comment: Please paste the code you're trying to create foreign key. There should not be any problem while creating 2 FKs referencing to 1 PK of another table considering their is no data mismatch if any.

Comment: This is the error I am getting when creating FK relationship via Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. Both tables are empty. "'Account' table saved successfully
'Voucher' table
- Unable to create relationship 'FK_Voucher_Account1'.  
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Voucher_Account1". The conflict occurred in database "SKUMAR", table "dbo.Account", column 'ID'.

"

Comment: Rename your second foreign key to something better. Rename your foreign keys like FK_Account_ID_Voucher_Crparty and FK_Account_ID_Voucher_Drparty

Comment: Its already different, first one is `FK_Voucher_Account` and second one is `FK_Voucher_Account1`

Comment: @Hemal Are you sure there is no data mismatch between second column with primary key, I think there might be.

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility of conflicted foreign key error because of data mismatch between `Voucher(CRPARTY)` column and `Account(Id)` column. Rows available in CRPARTY table must be in Account table.

Verify using below query.

```
SELECT * FROM Voucher WHERE CRPARTY NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM Account);
```

I was able to create 2 FKs to 1 PK. http://rextester.com/WMAT80057

Comment: I got it by emptying all related tables and then creating two FKs. Thanks.

Comment: One thing I would like to ask is why it was not creating FKs when there was data?Data in DRPARTY and CRPARTY column in voucher tables is available in Account table.

Comment: @Hemal wasn't there any mismatch between data, possibility of some rows which are available in CRPARTY column might not be available in Account(Id) column hence I asked to verify using above query.

Comment: You are right but that wasn't the case. I had two accounts with ID 1 and 2 in account table. I was creating a single voucher by adding 1 as DRPARTY and 2 as CRPARTY. But it was not allowing me to create second FK when data was present in both tables. Now when both tables are empty, I am able to create both FKs.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the FK relationships between your tables and use this script to create them. Hopefully, your tables do not have non matching data.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo]. [Voucher] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT  [FK_ACCOUNT_ID_VOUCHER_DRPARTY] FOREIGN KEY ([DRPARTY]) REFERENCES [dbo]. [Account]([ID])

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo]. [Voucher] CHECK  CONSTRAINT  [FK_ACCOUNT_ID_VOUCHER_DRPARTY] 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo]. [Voucher] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT  [FK_ACCOUNT_ID_VOUCHER_CRPARTY] FOREIGN KEY ([CRPARTY]) REFERENCES [dbo]. [Account]([ID])

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo]. [Voucher] CHECK  CONSTRAINT  [FK_ACCOUNT_ID_VOUCHER_CRPARTY] 
GO
```

Comment: I got it by emptying all related tables and then creating two FKs. Thanks.